# Change elements look with onclick attribute

Tags: html, events, onclick

I'd like to change the look of the elements with an onclick attribute to have them appear like links when a user puts his/her mouse cursor on them and I have no idea of how to do this.

Comment: sounds like you need onmouseover then

Comment: why the downvotes.. why not just help this person?

Comment: Explain the downvotes people!!

Comment: agreed... this is not an invalid question... aside form the apparent misunderstanding of what onclick does.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering and yes it would be nice to explain the downvotes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.color = 'red'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'">HaHAa!</div>
```

That's how you can do it inline, which it sounds like that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Typo: letter "m" on onmouseout

Comment: @Bruno lol :P I guess at least I can boast that I almost accurately wrote it from memory. XD Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

In CSS

```
element:hover
{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Isn't fully compatible with guess who! ... IE >.>

Comment: this is just an example going off of the vagueness